# Python returning this error even when I follow documentation - Quandl

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, quandl, zillow

So I have a bit of code in python which tries to get home prices from zillow. I am following the documentation exactly but I still get errors. The code:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "I have a key here in the code"

data = quandl.get("http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ZILL/S00022_A.csv", returns="numpy")
```

This, however, returns:

```
raise ValueError(Message.ERROR_COLUMN_INDEX_TYPE % dataset)
ValueError: The column index must be expressed as an integer for http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ZILL/S00022_A.csv.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a link to documentation that you used?

Comment: @kvorobiev https://docs.quandl.com/docs/python-tables

Comment: But you using `quandl.get`, not `quandl.get_table`. As far as I now, you couldn't pass an url as argument to `quandl.get`. If you want to get it as csv file you could use `urllib` for it, or just get it with `curl`/webbrowser. With `get` you could get any data series, for example `data = quandl.get("ZILLOW/M208_ZRISFRR", returns="numpy")`.

Comment: @kvorobiev Thanks. This works, but when I try to do `data = quandl.get("ZILLOW/CO182_A", returns="numpy")` It just says the quandl code is invalid. I know the problem is in `_A`. I just want all house prices!